# Shell Init Error trying to install Webpack

Tags: macos, webpack, getcwd

I am trying to install Webpack on OSX Sierra. I used the Sudo command and this is what I am getting

```
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied
path.js:1142
cwd = process.cwd();
^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, uv_cwd

at Error (native)
at Object.resolve (path.js:1142:25)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:127:32)
at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
/usr/local/lib
```